# How do I make a datamember optional on deserialization?

Tags: wcf, datacontractserializer

I have an xml where the TimeStamp is not set. I have tried every possible combination here but on deserialization it always throws an exception with: `There was an error deserializing the object of type MyType. The value '' cannot be parsed as the type 'DateTime'.`

```
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public DateTime TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
```

What exactly do I need to set on this TImeStamp member so that it is optional on deserialization (=not needed to be in the xml)

EDIT: What I tried on Xaruth's suggestion:

```
[DataMember]
[DefaultValue(typeof(DateTime), "2014-08-25T09:31:09.2477328+02:00")]
public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

public bool ShouldSerializeTimeStamp()
{
    return TimeStamp != null;
}

public void ResetTimeStamp()
{
    TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: Don't include in the serialization process. Since, it's a optional member; don't pass it while consuming the service method/operation.

Comment: Rahul I'm serializing to/from xml. The issue comes up when trying to deserialize an already existing xml which does not have the Timestamp at all but I still want it to deserialize without exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use methods `SouldSerialize` and `Reset`, wich can be define for any properties.

For a property called `TimeStamp`, you can write methods `SouldSerializeTimeStamp` and `ResetTimeStamp`

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e%28VS.71%29.aspx), `ResetTimeStamp` will give you a default value for `TimeStamp` and `SouldSerializeTimeStamp` will be used to serialize or not `TimeStamp`.

Comment: that does not seem to be related to Datacontracts/Datamember serialization

Comment: It does in fact ;) Try it, and see if it answer your problem.

Comment: Xaruth I tried your suggestion but still the same error. I edited my post.

Comment: @Xaruth u talking about a 3rd Party Serializer, propably Newtonsoft.Json. Check your referecnes ;-)